# ResponseEntity<MyDTO> is Returning Missing/Incomplete JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm seeing an issue with JSON cut-off/missing/incomplete when getting a response back from my service in Spring Boot.

Example:

```
ResponseEntity<MyDTO> responseEntity = myService.getMyDTO();
return responseEntity;
```

```
public class MyService {
  public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> getMyDTO() {
    return restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), MyDTO.class)
  }
}
```

When debugging and inspecting the body of ResponseEntity, which is MyDTO instance, it contains
all the expected fields.

```
public class MyDTO {
  private Information information;
  private Address address;
}

public class Information {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}

public class Address {
  private String streetName;
}
```

Debugging:

```
MyDTO
  body
    information
      firstName > "John"
      lastName > "Doe"
    address > null
```

Expected JSON:

```
{
  "information": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  "address: null
}
```

Actual JSON:

```
{
  "information": {
    "firstName": "Jo
```

Yes, the ending brackets are even missing from the response JSON.

**Note: address is null because the response from upstream service returns a 400 and we map that response to our DTO (MyDTO). Initially, I thought this was the problem until debugging confirmed that the mapping was done correctly.**

Here's what's really strange. If I take that ResponseEntity's body and put it in another ResponseEntity, than it returns fine and works. The service even returns faster, which is weird too.

```
ResponseEntity responseEntity = myService.getMyDTO();
return new ResponseEntity(responseEntity.getBody(), responseEntity.getStatusCode());
```

Anyone knows what's going on? Is it a networking, Spring Boot, or my code issue? Why would returning a new ResponseEntity fix the issue?

Comment: Can you share the code for `myService.getMyDTO();`?

Comment: Just added the code for MyService.getMyDTO

Comment: I think it's the timeout. What's the timeout for RestTemplate request?

Comment: I didn't think about that but not sure if that's the case since all the fields of MyDTO are present. It's only unexpected on client side.

Comment: The client must be dropping the connection when the exception occurs

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. The upstream service contains a 'Content-Length' header, which is too small and causing the missing/incomplete JSON on client-side.

Comment: Yeah, if you modify body of `ResponseEntity` before passing it to client, this header becomes invalid and it's causing strange issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are calling the `restTemplate.exchange()` method; if you use the `getForObject()` method (in case of post call `postForObject()`) instead it will work.

This method will first create the MyDTO class object and then you need to add that object in the ResponseEntity object to return it.

Example:

```
MyDTO myDtoObject = restTemplate.getForObject(requestUrl, MyDTO.class);
return new ResponseEntity<>(myDtoObject, HttpStatus.OK);
```